# Getting started with SLIME and SWANK: Lisp connection closed unexpectedly: connection broken by remote peer

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime, sbcl, swank

I was trying to use the slime-connect function to get access to a remote server with sbcl. I followed all the steps from the slime.mov movie from [Marco Baringer,](http://www.guba.com/watch/30000548671) but I got stuck when creating the ssh connection for slime. This is after already starting the swank server on the remote machine. I did it like this:

`ssh -L 4005:127.0.0.1:4005 user@server.com`

And I got this errors, on local SLIME:

Lisp connection closed unexpectedly: connection broken by remote peer

...and on the remote server:

channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Thanks all for your answers, slime-connect was not working for me so I put this on hold and instead installed emacs on the server so I just SLIME there. But then again, classes have started so I'm not currently doing any Common Lisp development.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked that the version of SLIME and SWANK you use are the same? I've had odd things happening when I've used mismatched versions of those two halves of a SLIME session.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, but you can try to connect to swank on remote machine locally.

```
ssh user@server.com
telnet 127.0.0.1:4005
```

May be there you will find errors. Also you can try localhost:4005 instead of 127.0.0.1 and check if localhost interface is properly configured.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to miss is the tcp port the swank server listens on.  I haven't been doing a lot of remote development lately, but I remember that the first times I did, I had a bit of trouble understanding how to tell swank which port to bind, or to find out which one it picked.

Would you mind expanding on how you actually started the swank server?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the `slime` (v2.22) function from Emacs started with additional argument `from-emacs t` which `swank-loader.lisp` didn't support (v2.22).

What worked for me is editing of `slime-v2.22/swank-loader.lisp:init` to accept one new argument `from-emacs` which isn't used of cause in the function's body, because I don't know in what way this argument should be treated. But `slime` starts now fine and workable.

Also while starting `slime` I receive a warning about incompatible versions: slime v2.23 and swank v2.22, but as I checked with `list-packages` and simply by folder names -- I have `slime` and `swank` both of versions v2.22. That's a confusion for me right now.

If somebody knows details about it, please, comment.