# Lisp IDE Portacle tells me "lisp connection closed unexpectedly connection broken by remote peer"

Tags: connection, lisp, common-lisp

So every time I try to run a code, it first gives me that message and then just "Not connected". How can I fix this?

There is a very similar question [Getting started with SLIME and SWANK: Lisp connection closed unexpectedly: connection broken by remote peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372750/getting-started-with-slime-and-swank-lisp-connection-closed-unexpectedly-conne) but I'm using Portacle and as far as I know it should take care of stuff like slime.

Comment: Tried again today, and for some reason it worked for about an hour, before returning to "not connected".

Comment: It worked after a day, and I've been using it for a while without any problems. Still curious about why this happened though.